# Fourier transform using exponential with positive argument as basis

Tags: fourier-transform

Fourier transform is normally performed with $e^{ikx}$ as basis. However, in a textbook which I am using, it used $e^{-ikx}$ as basis. Is this something valid to do?

Comment: Isn't by chance $k\in\mathbb Z$?

Comment: I just realized I got the sign in the exponential wrong way round. Also, I apologise I do not understand what you mean Andrew.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It makes no difference, providing consistency is maintained (rules like those for the derivative and shift have signs changed): since all $k$ are covered, and $k \mapsto -k$ is a bijection, you can replace $k$ with $-k$ without affecting the *content* of the theory, although as mentioned, lots of the rules you are used to have to be modified to be consistent in terms of the actual *numbers* that appear in formulae.

Indeed, there are other conventions that scale $k$, normally using $e^{-2\pi i k}$, or change the constants in front of the transform. One has a general Fourier transform dependent on two parameters,
$$ \mathcal{F}_{a,b}(f)(k) = \sqrt{\frac{\lvert b \rvert}{(2\pi)^{1-a}}} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x) e^{ibkx} \, dx, $$
with inverse
$$ \mathcal{F}_{a,b}^{-1}(g)(k) = \sqrt{\frac{\lvert b \rvert}{(2\pi)^{1+a}}} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} g(k) e^{-ibkx} \, dk, $$
where $(a,b)$ has different values depending on the convention in the field: Mathematica's documentation lists $(0,1)$ (modern physics), $(1,-1)$ (pure mathematics; systems engineering), $(-1,1)$ (classical physics), and $(0,-2\pi)$ (signal processing), for example. I like $(0,-2\pi)$ myself: keeps the $2\pi$s to a minimum in things like Parseval. But there is no universal convention, so it is normally defined when introduced, even in papers.